# Mutilple middlewares for routes didn't works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

I created 4 middlewares, one middleware by user role.

The admin has same rights as the employee. However, admin owns some more privileges.

**Routing File:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

    // EMPLOYEE AND ADMIN ROUTES
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin', 'employe']], function() {
         Route::get('showCreationSeance', 'AdministrationController@showCreationSeance');
         Route::get('showAjoutCoach', 'AdministrationController@showAjoutCoach');
         Route::get('showReservationClient', 'AdministrationController@showReservationClient');
         Route::get('showAnnulationClient', 'AdministrationController@showAnnulationClient');

         Route::post('creerSeance', 'AdministrationController@creerSeance')->name('admin/creerSeance');
         Route::post('ajouterCoach', 'AdministrationController@ajouterCoach')->name('admin/ajouterCoach');
    });

    // ADMIN ROUTES
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
         Route::get('showCreationActivite', 'AdministrationController@showCreationActivite');
         Route::get('showAjoutEmploye', 'AdministrationController@showAjoutEmploye');

         Route::post('creerActivite', 'AdministrationController@creerActivite')->name('admin/creerActivite');
         Route::post('ajouterEmploye', 'AdministrationController@ajouterEmploye')->name('admin/ajouterEmploye');
     });
});
```

**Middlewares:**

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = User::getUser(Auth::user()->id_utilisateur);

        if(!$user->estAdmin()) {
            throw new AuthorizationException();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

class EmployeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = User::getUser(Auth::user()->id_utilisateur);

        if(!$user->estEmploye()) {
            throw new AuthorizationException();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Methods used into middlewares:**

```
public function estAdmin() {
    $idStatutAdmin = Statut::select('id_statut')
        ->where('nom_statut', '=', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
        ->first();

    return ($idStatutAdmin->id_statut == $this->id_statut) ? true : false;
}

public function estEmploye() {
    $idStatutEmployee = Statut::select('id_statut')
        ->where('nom_statut', '=', 'ROLE_EMPLOYEE')
        ->first();

    return ($idStatutEmployee->id_statut == $this->id_statut) ? true : false;
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler render
…/app/Exceptions/Handler.php 51

Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException 
…/app/Http/Middleware/AdminMiddleware.php 25

Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel handle
…/public/index.php 55
```

**The problem:**
The routes defined for admin and employee didn't work and I get an error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ AccessDeniedHttpException
>
> No message

While routes for admin only work perfectly. Can you tell me if I'm doing this correctly?

When I'm connected as an admin, it is `EmployeMiddleware` which throw an error. And when I'm connected as employee, it is `AdminMiddleware` which throw an error.

Thank's for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to narrow down where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Yes it is on the AdminMiddleware. I think it's because the user connected is an employee. It is possible?

Comment: I've got no idea, you haven't posted the code for your middleware.

Comment: @JimWright I updated my question with middlewares codes. Tell me if you need more code.

Comment: Hi @N.Lamblin, could you also post your stacktrace for the error? That would help narrow down what is causing the error.

Comment: Of course, I updated my question with `Applications Frames`. I'm connected as an employee in this case. And the exception throw is on `AdminMiddleware`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user has the `id_statut` column which can only be `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_EMPLOYEE`. Take the following example:

```
$roles = [
    'admin' => 2,
    'employee' => 1
];

$user = [
    'id_statut' => 1
];

if ($user['id_statut'] == $roles['employee']) {
    // User is an employee - this code will execute
}
if ($user['id_statut'] == $roles['admin']) {
    // User is not an admin - this code will NOT execute
}
if ($user['id_statut'] == $roles['employee'] && $user['id_statut'] == $roles['employee']) {
    // User is an employee AND an admin
    // This is impossible based on your database structure as id_statut cannot be both 1 and 2
}
```

An easy solution would be to check if the user is an employee or higher permission in `estEmploye()`. For example:

```
public function estEmploye() {
    $idStatutEmployee = Statut::select('id_statut')
        ->where('nom_statut', 'IN', ['ROLE_EMPLOYEE', 'ROLE_ADMIN'])
        ->get('id_statut');
    return in_array($this->id_status, $idStatutEmployee);
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer! Just, `$idStatutEmployee` is an object and `in_array()` needs an array.   I had to edit my routing file and replace `Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin', 'employe']], function() {` by `Route::group(['middleware' => 'employe'], function() {`.

Comment: That will only ensure the user is an employee, I thought the whole point was that you wanted them to be an admin and employee?

Comment: To do that I updated my employee middleware too. `if($user->estEmploye() || $user->estAdmin())` because an admin is an employee.